# 404 on Store Switch with Product Store View Scoped URL Key

Tags: catalog, ce-1.7.0.2, store-view, url, language

By default `URL Key` on product page is Global scoped.

**EDIT:**
As suggested by FlorinelChis the scope can be changes in Manage attributes.
However this breaks the store view switcher behavior.

This is has been tested on 1.7.0.2 with samples data and **"Add store code to URL" enabled**:

1. edit a product and set a different url for a particular storeview (french)
2. Re-index
3. Open product page on the site on english store view
4. Switch to french: you will have the page URL containg `/French/`
5. Switch back to english -> 404 page error ( the url miss the store code `/default/`

   **how to make it work correctly with store view/language switch ?**

**Details:**

- URL for english : `/default/sony-vaio-vgn-txn27n-b-11-1-notebook-pc.html`
- URL for french : `/french/sony-vaio-vgn-txn27n-b-11-1-notebook-pc-french.html`

If I'm on english site on this page -> `/default/sony-vaio-vgn-txn27n-b-11-1-notebook-pc.html`

Then I switch to french:

I got this URL  (**the store code is missed**):
`MAGEDOMAIN/sony-vaio-vgn-txn27n-b-11-1-notebook-pc-french.html`

So magento re-write the url correctly but miss the store code for some reason

**Reference:**

For sure this is related to `/core/model/store.php` and `/core/model/url/rewrite.php`, and in particular to those methods:

`Mage_Core_Model_Url_Rewrite::rewrite`
`Mage_Core_Model_Store::getCurrentUrl`

**UPDATE**

If you are on 1.9.1 @Vinai fix will not work, check the new answer I have added

Comment: which Magento version are you using?

Comment: Magento 1.7.0.2

Comment: Tim I'm currently testing some answer and will accept them after confirm they are working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some updated info for Magento 1.9.1

The bug @Vinai pointed out looks solved in this version anyway for other reason the functionality is still broken ( for configurable products )

The problem real problem is probably here `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Url` however I don't have time and I dont' want to touch a such delicate part of the core.

**Explanation for a workaround:**

The entry point is always this class`Mage_Core_Model_Url_Rewrite_Request`
and in particular the method `_rewriteDb()`

**How `_rewriteDb()` works:**

1. First it try to load the request for the current store

*(139):* `$this->_rewrite->loadByRequestPath($requestCases);`

2. then if I cannot find it (no id) and has a `___from_store` parameter

*(142):* `if (!$this->_rewrite->getId() && $fromStore) {`

3. try to load a rewrite for the `___from_store`:

*(152):* `$this->_rewrite->setStoreId($fromStoreId)->loadByRequestPath($requestCases);`

4. if it find it, it use the `id_path` to load the one for the current store:

*(159):* `$this->_rewrite->setStoreId($currentStore->getId())->loadByIdPath($this->_rewrite->getIdPath());`

Everything looks fine however there is an issue in the url_rewrite data and so with the index functionality  ( at least for configurable products ):

- even if we are switching store and the new store has different url a rewrite at line 139 is loaded.

The problem is that this rewrite points to the wrong `id_path` ( instead of pointing to the configurable product id it is pointing to one of its simple product id )

Now a workaround is to remove the `!$this->_rewrite->getId()` condition and so magento try to find a redirect always when there a `$fromstore` parameter

- **The best would be to fix the `catalog_url` index and remove the wrong
  rewrite it creates.**

Here the code for the fast workaround ( you will need to create a module and rewrite `Mage_Core_Model_Url_Rewrite_Request` class by your self):

```
protected function _rewriteDb()
    {
        if (null === $this->_rewrite->getStoreId() || false === $this->_rewrite->getStoreId()) {
            $this->_rewrite->setStoreId($this->_app->getStore()->getId());
        }

        $requestCases = $this->_getRequestCases();
        $fromStore = $this->_request->getQuery('___from_store');

        if ($fromStore) {
            $stores = $this->_app->getStores(false, true);
            if (!empty($stores[$fromStore])) {
                /** @var $store Mage_Core_Model_Store */
                $store = $stores[$fromStore];
                $fromStoreId = $store->getId();
            } else {
                return parent::_rewriteDb();
            }

            $this->_rewrite->setStoreId($fromStoreId)->loadByRequestPath($requestCases);
            if (!$this->_rewrite->getId()) {
                return parent::_rewriteDb();
            }

            // Load rewrite by id_path
            $currentStore = $this->_app->getStore();
            $this->_rewrite->setStoreId($currentStore->getId())->loadByIdPath($this->_rewrite->getIdPath());

            $this->_setStoreCodeCookie($currentStore->getCode());

            $targetUrl = $currentStore->getBaseUrl() . $this->_rewrite->getRequestPath();
            $this->_sendRedirectHeaders($targetUrl, true);
        }

        if (!$this->_rewrite->getId()) {
            return parent::_rewriteDb();
        }

        $this->_request->setAlias(Mage_Core_Model_Url_Rewrite::REWRITE_REQUEST_PATH_ALIAS,
            $this->_rewrite->getRequestPath());
        $this->_processRedirectOptions();

        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 12):

The problem is a bug in the model `Mage_Core_Model_Url_Rewrite_Request` (Magento 1.8) and `Mage_Core_Model_Url_Rewrite` (earlier versions).

The section of core code in 1.8 looks like this:

```
    // Section from Mage_Core_Model_Url_Rewrite_Request::_rewriteDb()

    $fromStore = $this->_request->getQuery('___from_store');
    if (!$this->_rewrite->getId() && $fromStore) {
        $stores = $this->_app->getStores();
        if (!empty($stores[$fromStore])) {
            $store = $stores[$fromStore];
            $fromStoreId = $store->getId();
        } else {
            return false;
        }
```

The Bug: the value of the query parameter is the store code, (in my case `de`, `en` or `fr`).
The keys of the array returned by `app->getStores()` are the **numeric** store IDs.
Thats why `if (!empty($stores[$fromStore])) {` always fails.

Once that bug is fixed, another bug becomes apparent later in the same method (I think only in 1.8):

```
$targetUrl = $this->_request->getBaseUrl() . '/' . $this->_rewrite->getRequestPath();
```

The request objects base url always is the Magento base_url, *without* the store code.
Using `$currentStore->getBaseUrl()` instead there fixes that bug, too.

Once those two issues are fixed the language switcher works fine. Here is an extension which does exactly that for Magento 1.8 (CE): https://github.com/Vinai/VinaiKopp_StoreUrlRewrites

In Magento 1.7 the issue might be something different. I still thought I'd add this answer, just in case google brings somebody else here who is running 1.8 or newer.

Comment: do you think the fix I have implemented is safe ?

Comment: To be honest, I haven't looked into the cause for the issue in 1.7. Implementing a fix without understanding exactly what is causing the behavior is always risky.

Comment: sorry reopening this discussion after 2 years but I'm again on this bug ... on 1.9.1 the issue is with the if condition $this->_rewrite->getId() ... basically for the second store view magento manage to load a rewrite and so It doesn't trigger the redirect ... however this rewrite has the wrong id_path ( product id is +1 ) so it load a 404

Answer (score 4):

Actually I found a workaround for this issue on Magento 1.7.0.2 if you are running Magento 1.8 looks to Vinai's detailed explanation:

It looks that part of the problem is related to the request controller `Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http`.

If you look at line 161 there is this condition:

```
                elseif ($storeCode !== '') {
                    $this->setActionName('noRoute');
                }
```

Commenting it out fix the 404 error when I switch to a different Store in a category/product pages.

However for some unknown reason some time the store code is missed in the response Url but this is not causing issue anymore as both url works now:

- MAGEDOMAIN/sony-vaio-vgn-txn27n-b-11-1-notebook-pc-french.html
- MAGEDOMAIN/sony-vaio-vgn-txn27n-b-11-1-notebook-pc.html

**It is stil not clear to me if the comment of this condition can cause other issue**

Comment: I can confirm this works for me as well - whenever switching to another language when viewing a product, I would get a 404. This corrected it, and does as you said, omit the store code from the URL which is strange. I can't imagine this is the best solution as editing the core controller like this can't be good, I was wondering if you ever ended up finding another solution?

Comment: you don't need to edit any core file, you can create your own module and rewrite that class/method.

Comment: `Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http` cannot be rewritten in a module.

Answer (score 3):

**URL Key** is an attribute. You can edit it from: *Catalog -> Attributes -> Manage Attributes*.
Search for **url_key** and click on it.
[image: Edit url_key attribute]

Change the **Scope** and Save.

Now you can have different URL keys for products on each store view.

Comment: I have updated the question, you answer is good but it is not working

Comment: when you switch the store you should land on that store homepage not the product page.

Comment: The place where you land is the same where you start from: if you are on a category page you should land on the same page in the different language

Answer (score 1):

So you want to change the URL for each store view?

At present, you modified the product URL at the score scope for your French store to be different to your English store? And when you switch between the two, you get a 404. This would be expected behaviour.

Magento won't store different URL rewrites for other store views. So when you hit `/french/product1` on the French store, the URL will match in the table and it will load. But when you hit it in the English store, there will be no match and thus will 404.

What it sounds like you need is to just "Add store codes to URL" - which will leave your URL keys alone, but prefix all respective URLs with your store code. This should then allow your store switcher to function.

Comment: as confirmed by Vinai this is a bug