# Language switch on product page returns 404

Tags: store-view, language

Having trouble switching between languages on product view of Magento 1.8.1.0. Already tried extensions/solutions from [Vinai](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/728/switch-issue-404-error-store-view-scope-for-url-key-category-products) and [DGagliardi](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/fix-404-error-in-language-switching.html) resulting in same one-way redirection behaviour.

Our case:

**VIEWS:**

- Lithuanian (default)
- English

**Product info:**

- URL default: `product-title-in-lithuanian`
- URL lithuanian: "Use Default Value"
- URL english: `product-title-in-english`

**Behaviour**

- from Lithuanian view:

  - being on `/lt/product-title-in-lithuanian`
  - switching to english sends to `/en/product-title-in-lithuanian`
  - which itself redirects properly with 301 to `/en/product-title-in-english`
- from English view:

  - being on `/en/product-title-in-english`
  - switching to lithuanian sends to `/lt/product-title-in-english`
  - which DOES NOT redirect to `/lt/product-title-in-lithuanian` and ends with 404 error

Any tip what could be the problem here?

Comment: Easy described: The langauge switch expects the url key to be global, which you changed. No time to describe solution in detail, but there are two ways: either you add a redirect (if and only if) EVERY URL KEY is unique or you have to implement the mapping by yourself I think. Load the url_rewrite from the old store where you came from, get the product, get the correct url and redirect

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found my problem - I was not using the `___from_store` variable when switching store views. It is needed for the cross-view rewrite to happen properly. Restored the `___from_store` in the language switch template with `$_lang->getCurrentUrl()` and it's working fine now with [Vinai solution](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/728/switch-issue-404-error-store-view-scope-for-url-key-category-products). No 404s... phew... finally...